# Addition of 2 points on elliptic curve over finite field can have multiple / ambiguous results?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, elliptic-curves

Consider the curve $y^2 = x^3 + 1$ over the field $F_5$.

Let's add the points $(0, 4)$ and $(4, 0)$.

$\lambda = \frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1} = \frac{0 - 4}{4 - 0} = \frac{-4}{4} = \frac{1}{4} = 1 \cdot 4^{-1} = 1 \cdot 4 = 4$.

$x_3 = \lambda^2 - x_1 - x_2$

$x_3 = 16 - 0 - 4 =  1 - 4 = -3 = 2$

However, there are 2 valid points that have $x = 2$  on $E(F_5)$: $(2, 2), (2,3)$.

How do I know which point is the correct result?
The solution says: $(2, 3)$, but doesn't give a reason for one point over the other.

Note: The same ambiguity exists in $(4, 0) + (2, 3)$ on $E(F_5)$.

Comment: $(x_3,y_3)$ is on the line $y-y_1=\lambda(x-x_1)$ i.e. $y=4+4x$ so $x_3=2$ must give $y_3=2$. Now, reflecting across $x$-axis produces $(2,3)$. In other words, don't use the curve to find the "$y$", use the line.

Comment: You did not use [the group laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve#The_group_law) completely;